# AdaptiveClient - Library and pattern for consuming services across heterogeneous platforms and protocols

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I wrote a small client for a project I'm working on that allows me to connect to various implementations of the application API.  The client turned out to be so effortless and versatile that I decided to generalize it and publish it as its own library.  I would like some feedback on the design and usefulness of the pattern and the library - specifically: Is it even necessary given the widespread use of VPNs?  Is it over-engineered?  A wrong approach to begin with?  What specific recommendations do you have to improve it?

You can get the code for `AdaptiveClient` from [Github](https://github.com/leaderanalytics/AdaptiveClient).  You can also get a [simple colsole app demo](https://github.com/leaderanalytics/AdaptiveClient.SimpleConsoleDemo), or an [end-to-end working example application](https://github.com/leaderanalytics/AdaptiveClient.AdvancedDemo).  A [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AdaptiveClient) is also available.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private IAdaptiveClient<IUsersService> client;

    public MainWindow(IAdaptiveClient<IUsersService> client)
    {
        this.client = client;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(int userID)
    {
        // AdaptiveClient will use the best server available at the time 
        // the request is made. 
        // Server may be SQL, WCF, REST, etc. - your application does not need to know or care.
        // If the request fails AdaptiveClient will begin an orderly fall back to other 
        // servers that can handle the request regardless of platform or protocol:

        User user = await client.CallAsync(x => x.GetUser(userID));
    }
}
```

### What AdaptiveClient does

Rather than make a service call directly to a specific server or type of server you make a call using `AdaptiveClient` instead.  `AdaptiveClient` will attempt to execute the call using the best available server.  If the call fails `AdaptiveClient` will make successive attempts, each time falling back to other servers of the same type or other types.

For example, a mobile user who is on-site and connected to a local area network will enjoy the performance of an in-process connection directly to the database server.  If the user tries to reconnect from a remote location `AdaptiveClient` will attempt a LAN connection again but will fall back to a WebAPI server (for example) when the LAN connection fails.  Should the WebAPI connection fail, `AdaptiveClient` may attempt to connect to other WebAPI servers, a WCF server, or any other server as configured.

### Who will benefit from using it

- `AdaptiveClient` is ideally targeted to organizations that need to give local users access to their APIs over a local area network but who also wish to expose their APIs to remote users.
- Developers who want to implement retry and/or fall back logic when making service calls.

### How it works

`AdaptiveClient` is a design pattern that leverages [n-tier architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) and a dependency injection container.  The client and utility classes assist you in implementing the pattern.  The current version includes a client implementation based on Autofac.  You should be able to implement similar functionality using other DI containers.

All of you who have used a dependency injection container are familiar with the concept of registration:

```
builder.RegisterType<UsersService>().As<IUsersService>();
```

In the line above an implementation of an interface is associated with the interface so the container knows what implementation to return when the interface is resolved.
`AdaptiveClient` works in the same way but the registrations are slightly different.  Also, `AdaptiveClient` uses a small configuration file to maintain metadata about EndPointsConfigurations.  An `EndPointConfiguration` (a.k.a EndPoint for short) is like a connection string or a URL but it includes some extra properties that are useful:

- **Name**: Name of the EndPoint: DevServer01, QASloth02, etc.
- **API_Name**:  Name of the application or API exposed by the EndPoint: OurCompanyApp, xyz.com, etc.  NOT the name of a contract or interface.
- **Preference**:  Number that allows ClientFactory to rank this EndPoint.  Lower numbers are ranked higher (more preferred).
- **EndPointType**:  May be one of the following:  InProcess, HTTP, WCF, ESB.  Assists ClientFactory in determining if the EndPoint is alive.  Multiple EndPointConfigurations of the same `EndPointType` may be defined for an API_Name.
- **ConnectionString**:  Valid connection string OR URL if pointing to a HTTP server.
- **Parameters**:  Not used at this time.
- **IsActive**:  Set this value to false to prevent using this `EndPointConfiguration`.

When you register the components of your application with your DI container you also register your EndPoints with Adatapive client.  You register the EndPoints with a couple lines of code like this:

```
RegistrationHelper registrationHelper = new RegistrationHelper(builder);
IEnumerable<IEndPointConfiguration> endPoints = ... // read endpoints from config file 
registrationHelper.RegisterEndPoints(endPoints);
```

Each EndPoint in your config file has an API Name (API Name is just a string of your choosing).  When you register your interfaces you associate them with an API Name - which effectively associates them with the collection of EndPoints that expose them:

```
// psudocode
Interfaces (IUsersService, IOrdersService) are registered with API Name `MyAppAPI` which is registered with EndPoints (ProdSQLServer01, ProdWebServer01, ProdWebServer02, ProdWCFServer01)
Interfaces(IChargeUser, IRefundUser) are registered with API Name `BankAPI` which is registered with EndPoints (BankServer01, BankServer02)
```

Each EndPoint has an EndPointType (WebAPI, REST, WCF, etc) which helps `AdaptiveClient` resolve a specific client (implementation of your interface) for use with a specific EndPoint.

For example you may register UsersServiceRESTClient, UsersServiceWCFClient, and UsersServiceWebAPIClient with IUsersService.  When you request an implementation of IUsersService and `AdaptiveClient` finds a working EndPoint of type HTTP, `AdaptiveClient` will know to return the UsersServiceRESTClient.

`AdaptiveClient` has a helper class for Autofac that allows you to register your clients with just a few lines of code:

```
string apiName = "OurCompanyAPI";
// client that communicates directly with the database (the service itself)
registrationHelper.Register<MyApp.Services.UsersService, IUsersService>(EndPointType.InProcess, apiName);
// WebAPI client 
registrationHelper.Register<MyApp.WebAPIClient.UsersClient, IUsersService>(EndPointType.HTTP, apiName);
// WCF client 
registrationHelper.Register<MyApp.WCFClient.UsersClient, IUsersService>(EndPointType.WCF, apiName);
```

Now that you know how the components of your application are registered with `AdaptiveClient`, the process of resolving a client as explained in the diagram below should make sense.

### How `AdaptiveClient` resolves a client from start to finish:

[image: alt an image]

Comment: It seems like this belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: @FrankHileman First paragraph.

Comment: Agree that this is a code review, not a focused question.